# Why does using a semaphore in a seperate thread freeze up the program?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I had this problem, so I boiled it down to the minimum program that still exhibited this error. I am on Windows.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE m_mutex;

void runFunction()
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_mutex, 1, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    m_mutex = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(m_mutex, INFINITE);

    HANDLE m_handle = CreateThread(0, 5120, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(runFunction), 0, 0, 0); 

    WaitForSingleObject(m_mutex, INFINITE);
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_mutex, 1, NULL);

    TerminateThread(m_handle, 0);
    CloseHandle(m_handle);

    CloseHandle(m_mutex);

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ignore the poor coding style and the use of TerminateThread (I know that using that is bad), this is a case I am testing not one that I would implement. Still I would like to know why this freezes up the program, especially when something as simple as putting `std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;` in the middle makes the program no longer freeze. Also, "done" is printed, just the program never exits.

Comment: Not your problem, but note http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but that's to be expected if it's a race condition.  Most likely cause is the call to TerminateThread corrupting some data structure the runtime library depends on.

Comment: FWIW, you could probably mask the symptoms by calling `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0)` to exit the process instead of returning from main().

Answer (score 1):

The logic looks OK concerning the Semaphore. My apologies. I've not noticed the "1". I can only mention that you don't verify that the API functions actually complete successfully.

```
void runFunction()
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_mutex, 1, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    //OK - Count=1
    m_mutex = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(m_mutex, INFINITE);

    //OK - Count=0

    HANDLE m_handle = CreateThread(0, 5120, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(runFunction), 0, 0, 0); 

    //DO you know for sure that the thread has started??? The return value is never checked???

    //Now we not sure... Count may 1, or 0, because thread is not necessarily started immediately..

    //OK. We will block here. Count should no be 1 again, or should soon become it
    WaitForSingleObject(m_mutex, INFINITE);

    //Why???
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_mutex, 1, NULL);

    //Why so extreme? "Terminate thread is a dangerous function...." MSDN
    TerminateThread(m_handle, 0);
    CloseHandle(m_handle);

    CloseHandle(m_mutex);

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. The Semaphore has a count of 1, meaning that "WaitForSingleObject" is essentially just locking a lock (it's a mutex), and then ReleaseSemaphore is unlocking the lock. You can run it yourself and see that it continues running after that.

Comment: So I release the Semaphore again because it is essentially unlocking a lock, and since we just locked it it is good practice to unlock it.

Comment: Then I agree TerminateThread is something that should not be used, but if someone is making a thread class (there's where I got this code), it's really the only option of halting a thread on a .stop(). It's bad practice, and ideally there shouldn't be a stop() (only a join, and then the programmer should implement stop as needed in their code via polling or a mutex or critical section or etc.), however this exists in production code and I would like to know why it breaks.

Comment: Yes, but you never wait on it again. You've created it with one extra count to begin with. 1 its its maximum count. Now Release would cause it to exceed 1, not???

Comment: Nah, remember release decrements the count. It's essentially a "unlock." So my WaitForSingleObject incremented it to 1, then my ReleaseSemaphore set it back down to 0.

Comment: From MSDN

lReleaseCount [in]
The amount by which the semaphore object's current count is to be increased. The value must be greater than zero. If the specified amount would cause the semaphore's count to exceed the maximum count that was specified when the semaphore was created, the count is not changed and the function returns FALSE. Therefore Release increases the count. Wait decreases and blocks when zero is reached (when it is non-signalled). Remember - Release increments, wait decrements.